# How to Fix Undefined Variable id error in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, firebase, laravel-5

M working on a solution where by i need to pass data from controller to view, Based on the id.

I've tested each variable one by one for see if there is actual data contained in those variables.

one-by-one produces all the values required and as soon as i comment out the var_dumps(). Throws an Undefined index error.

Please See code below:

View

```
<td>
   <a href="view-campaign/{{$item->id}}" class="btn btn-success mb-2"
      data-toggle="tooltip" title="view campaign">                            
        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
   </a>
</td>
```

Controller

```
public function viewCampaign($id){

        //return var_dump($id);

        $img = null;

        //firebase configs and send to firebase
        $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/serviceKey.json');
        $firebase = (new Factory)
            ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
            ->withDatabaseUri('https://projectName.firebaseio.com/')
            ->create();

            $database = $firebase->getDatabase();

            $ref = $database->getReference('CampaignCollection')->getValue();

            foreach($ref as $key){
                $item = $key['id'];
                //return var_dump($item); 
                $poster = $key['Poster'];
                //return var_dump($poster); 
                if($item = $id){ 

                    //return '1';
                    $img = $poster; 
                    //return var_dump($poster);
                }else{
                    return '0';
                }
             }
        return view('view-campaign')->with('img',$img);
    }
```

Route

```
Route::get('view-campaign/{id}','CampaignController@viewCampaign');
```

View::Results

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12 panel">
            <div class="col-md-12 panel-heading">
                <h4>View Campaign:</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="imgContainer" class="col-md-12 panel-body">
               <a href="/listCampaign" class="btn btn-danger mb-2" style="margin-bottom: 15px"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a>
               @if(isset($img))
                  <div  align="center">
                    <img src="{{($img)}}" />
                  </div>
                @else
                  no data 
                @endif

            </div>    
        </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Goal is to get the base64 code to pass to the view.

Comment: What's throwing the error? What file, what line? Have you isolated the issue?

Comment: @swonder the controller is throwing the error on line  $item = $key['id'];

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($key);` (as the first statement in the loop, before `$item = $key['id'];`, don’t return it)? Alternatively `var_dump($ref->getChildKeys()`. It looks like the Reference doesn’t contain what you expect it to contain (= it has no key with the name “id”)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your foreach with the following code:

```
foreach($ref as $k1 => $key){
                $item = $key->id; //change over here
                //return var_dump($item); 
                $poster = $key->Poster;  //change over here
                //return var_dump($poster); 
                if($item == $id){ //change over here

                    //return '1';
                    $img = $poster; 
                    //return var_dump($poster);
                }else{
                    return '0';
                }
             }
```

I reckon, you would also have to update the function signature to look something like following:

```
public function viewCampaign(Request $request , $id){
            //your code
}
```

Comment: now its responding the error "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"